# Lottie Framework issues - animation won't run

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lottie

I tried running an animation out of a JSON file which was created in After Effects with the Bodymovin Extension, but unfortunatelly I can't get the animation running in my simulations. The JSON file itself works since I've demoed it on a HTML page and it works fluently. So there must be something wrong in the code. I've already tried out many tutorials, so many variations of coding lines with no success.

The JSON file is simply dragged into my Xcode project, which is called "fire". The only I have to do is inside the "ViewController" according to many tutorials. There are no issues building it but when simulating it, there's only a blank screen on the iPhone. And right after running, it automatically opens the debugging console in Xcode but there aren't any errors.

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var animationView: AnimationView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let animation = Animation.named("fire")
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationView.loopMode = .loop
        animationView.play()
    }
}
```

I've noticed in my research that the Lottie commands are changing from time to time. This should be the latest correct commands, but I might be wrong.

After making some given corrections, I'm getting a crash in one thread after successfully building. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Add the animation view to your top view.

```
topView.addSubview(animationView)
```

Make sure you setup the constraints also.

```
    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([xConstraint, yConstraint])
```

Comment: I'm getting an unresolved identifier for "topView".

Comment: or u can simply set the frame self.animationview.frame = self.topview.frame

Comment: add self.view instead of topView

Comment: I just added topView and animationView terms just to clarify the flow

Comment: Please check the above update I made of the situation

Comment: Dont update the question. If you have new issue, create a new question. This way will be helpful for other developers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let animation = Animation.named("fire")
    animationView.animation = animation
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    animationView.loopMode = .loop
    animationView.play()
    animationview.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(animationView)
```

Change the `view` to a subview if u need it to fit in a specific view

Comment: @zumry mohamed answer is correct.. I just posted this for clarification